# ¿Como mandar llamar una funcion .js desde un boton de asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Como mando llamar una funcion de javascript desde asp.net, ya lo hice de diferentes formas, pero me marca undefined,campo vacio, o no me marcaba nada y en lo que a mi respecta la forma de hacerlo es asi.

Codigo para obtener valor de un textbox.

```
var nick = $('#<%=txtNick.ClientID%>').text(); 
alert(nick);
var nick = $('#<%=txtNick.ClientID%>').val(); 
alert(nick);
var nick = document.getElementById("<%= txtNick.ClientID %>").value;
```

Codigo del textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNick"
        runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Codigo del boton que deberia activar la funcion.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnEntrar" runat="server" Text="Entrar" OnClientClick="return autenticarme();" />
```

Comment: ¿Al pulsar el botón deseas obtener el texto del `TextBox` y manejarlo con código JavaScript?

Comment: @Flxtr si quiero hacer eso para luego mandarlo con una llamada ajax a un metodo de C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza `OnClientClick`:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLlamaFuncionJS" runat="server" Text="Botón" OnClientClick="funcionJS()"/>
```

Código JavaScript:

```
function funcionJS() {
    //Código JavaScript
}
```

Para obtener el valor utiliza comillas simples en lugar de comillas dobles:

```
var nick = document.getElementById('<%= txtNick.ClientID %>').value;
```

Si deseas utilizar jQuery utiliza directamente el `Id` del control:

```
var nick = $(".txtNick").val();
```

## Actualización

Realicé un pequeño ejercicio acerca de tu problema y pude obtener el contenido de la caja de texto y asignarla a una variable justo con el mismo código que puse al inicio. El código del archivo ASPX es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function autenticarme() {
        var nick = document.getElementById('<%= txtNick.ClientID %>').value;
        alert(nick);
        return true;
    }
</script>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNick" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnEntrar" runat="server" Text="Entrar" OnClientClick="return autenticarme();" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si uso OnClientClick

Comment: @David edité mi respuesta :)

Comment: con class="txtNick"  si funciona pero con el id ya no me funcion me dice en el alert undefined.

Comment: @David estoy realizando un ejercicio, dame unos minutos :)

Comment: si esta bien, no te preocupes

Comment: @David he podido replicar el caso, actualicé mi respuesta para que tomes como referencia el código. A todo esto me surge una pregunta, ¿en tu código tienes definida la etiqueta `<form>`? Es importante que esté para que los controles pertenezcan a un formulario.

Comment: noestan en un formulario, ¿es obligatorio el form?

Comment: @David es obligatorio para poder hacer uso de los controles

Comment: gracias, ya se resolvio.